# How can I access 1 tomcat app from 2 different contexts?

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible to load same application called from different URLs?

I have tried different configs with `mod_rewrite` but its not working. I am currently trying with virtual hosts but not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that since you are mentioning that you are using mod_rewrite, you are fronting, Tomcat with Apache?
If so, why not use Apache as a reverse proxy?

An example config for Apache would be:  Where Tomcat is assumed to run on Port 8080 with Tomcat's ROOT context serving out the application.

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName url1.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *>
    ServerName url2.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
 </VirtualHost>
```